# Implementing AlgorithmM of TAOCP vol 4 fascicle 2 using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have tried to implement what the title says but because of lazy evaluation I cannot take result:

```
data AlgorithmM = AlgorithmM {fm::[Int],fa::[Int],fj::Int,fn::Int}
m1a :: AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM)
m1a (AlgorithmM m a j n) = (return (),AlgorithmM (2:m) a j n)

m1b :: AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM)
m1b (AlgorithmM m a j n) = (return (),AlgorithmM m (take n $! repeat 0) j n)


m2 algo = (visit False $ fa algo,algo)
  where visit True l =do
             mapM (\z->putStr $ show z) l
             putStr "\n"
    visit False (x:xs) = do
                          mapM (\z->putStr $ show z) xs
                          putStr "\n"
initN :: AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM)
initN (AlgorithmM m a j n) = (return (),AlgorithmM m a j ((length m)-1))

m3 :: AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM)
m3 (AlgorithmM m a j n) = (return (),AlgorithmM m a n n)


m4 :: AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM)
m4 (AlgorithmM m a j n) = if (a !! j) == (m !! j) - 1 then m4 (AlgorithmM m (setajZero a j) (j-1) n) else  (return (),AlgorithmM m a j n)
 where setajZero (x:xs) 0 = 0:xs
       setajZero (x:xs) j = x:(setajZero xs (j-1))

m5 :: AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM)
m5 (AlgorithmM m a j n) = if j==0 then (return (),AlgorithmM m a j n) else m2 (AlgorithmM m a j n)

bind :: (IO(),AlgorithmM)->(AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM))->(IO(),AlgorithmM)
bind g f = f $! snd g 

testAlgorithmM = m1a (AlgorithmM [2,2,2] [] 0 0) `bind` initN `bind` m1b `bind` m2 `bind` m3 `bind` m4 `bind` m5

main = do
    let (x,y) = testAlgorithmM
    x
```

When I run the above code to the interpreter I take

> Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large

What I think is that the list in m1a does not expand n+1 so m4 throws the exception

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Oh man, you are going to _love_ [`StateT AlgorithmM IO ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT).

Answer (score 2):

As the poster above me said, you improperly indexed your lists. Replace `(a !! j) == (m !! j) - 1` with `(a !! (j - 1)) == (m !! (j - 1)) - 1` and it will work.

However, all of your superfluous `return ()` statements do not do anything. It seems you have a misunderstanding of the role of monads and specifically `IO`. You also seem to believe that laziness makes your code not work; while this is technically true, the problem is not that haskell is lazy but rather you have not told it what you want to compute.

I have modified the code to eliminate all of the `return ()` statements. Note that I have not changed the execution of the code. It will execute everything in the exact same order as the original.

```
data AlgorithmM = AlgorithmM {fm::[Int],fa::[Int],fj::Int,fn::Int} deriving Show

m1a :: AlgorithmM -> AlgorithmM
m1a (AlgorithmM m a j n) = AlgorithmM (2:m) a j n

m1b :: AlgorithmM -> AlgorithmM
m1b (AlgorithmM m a j n) = AlgorithmM m (take n $! repeat 0) j n

m2 :: AlgorithmM -> (String, AlgorithmM)
m2 algo = (visit False $ fa algo,algo)
  where visit True l = (concatMap show l) ++ "\n"
        visit False (x:xs) = concatMap show xs ++ "\n"

initN :: AlgorithmM -> AlgorithmM
initN (AlgorithmM m a j n) = AlgorithmM m a j ((length m)-1)

m3 :: AlgorithmM-> AlgorithmM
m3 (AlgorithmM m a j n) = AlgorithmM m a n n


m4 :: AlgorithmM -> AlgorithmM
m4 (AlgorithmM m a j n) = if (a !! (j - 1)) == (m !! (j - 1)) - 1 then m4 (AlgorithmM m (setajZero a j) (j-1) n) else AlgorithmM m a j n
 where setajZero (x:xs) 0 = 0:xs
       setajZero (x:xs) j = x:(setajZero xs (j-1))

m5 :: AlgorithmM -> (String, AlgorithmM)
m5 (AlgorithmM m a j n) = if j==0 then ("", AlgorithmM m a j n) else m2 (AlgorithmM m a j n)

testAlgorithmM = s0
    where (s0, a) = m2 $ m1b $ initN $ m1a (AlgorithmM [2,2,2] [] 0 0)
          b       = m5 $ m4 $ m3 a
```

If you inspect `m2` you will notice you call `visit False` every time. You can further reduce this to

```
m2 :: AlgorithmM -> (String, AlgorithmM)
m2 algo = ((\xs -> concatMap show xs ++ "\n") $ tail $  fa algo,algo)
```

I have simply replace the `visit` function with the branch of the function corresponding to `False`.

Then there is the issue of what happens in `testAlgorithmM`. Again, the execution is the same (I have just removed the strictness property). But note that since the value of `testAlgorithmM` is `s0`, it will not evaluate `m5 $ m4 $ m3 a` because the value of it is not needed to produce the desired output. With your original code it was impossible to see this was happening, but when you remove all of the obfuscation it is glaringly obvious.

Creating a string in the middle of your chain of function applications seems to be a way of saving some intermediate state. If that is the case, you should look into the [ST monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad/ST). It does the same things that `IO` does except you can't `print` or `putStrLn`. But, you can just do these things after you have performed all of your computation.

If you want your entire chain of algorithm transformations to be calculated, you must do the following:

```
testAlgorithmM = (b,s0)
    where (s0, a) = m2 $ m1b $ initN $ m1a (AlgorithmM [2,2,2] [] 0 0)
          b       = m5 $ m4 $ m3 a
```

This also outputs your intermediate string value, in case you want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, laziness should never have observable effects on the value of a pure function (barring **highly** pathological situations).  So a list indexing error can't be the result of too much laziness.

Let's say we take our error message at face value, and guess that the error is coming from `m4`, which calls `Prelude.!!` directly.  Let's use [GHCi's debugger](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html):

```
ghci> :break m4
ghci> :step main
ghci> :continue
Stopped at foo.hs:(24,1)-(26,50)
ghci> :step
Stopped at foo.hs:24:27-137
_result :: (IO (), AlgorithmM) = _
a :: [Int] = _
j :: Int = _
m :: [Int] = _
n :: Int = _
ghci> :list
23  m4 :: AlgorithmM->(IO (),AlgorithmM)
24  m4 (AlgorithmM m a j n) =
      if (a !! j) == (m !! j) - 1
         then m4 (AlgorithmM m (setajZero a j) (j-1) n)
         else  (return (),AlgorithmM m a j n)
25   where setajZero (x:xs) 0 = 0:xs
ghci> :force a j m n
a = [0,0,0]
j = 3
m = [2,2,2,2]
n = 3
```

Guess what's going to happen next?

Answer (score 0):

That error means your index is past the end of the list; nothing to do with laziness. Take a look at [the implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#%21%21).

Your implementation is just wrong apparently. Perhaps you only proved it correct?